# Pull latest data from database using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I want to use NodeJS for live graphs for that reason, I want to pull latest data from database using NodeJS and then push to UI. Is there any possible solution in NodeJS.

I am using Cassandra database.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://xingwu.me/2014/10/19/Real-time-Web-Dashboard-Using-Socket-io-and-Highcharts/

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad. If you want to poll your database on a timer you could use

```
setInterval(() =>{
  // Read data from database here
  // Send data to client
});
```

To send data to clients you could use a tool like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which is easy to implement and works great with real time data! There is a great example [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) how to us socket.io to send data between a server and a client.

Comment: I want to stream data from cassandra using nodejs, i.e. I should get only the newly inserted rows in cassandra

Comment: Socket.io will not get data from Cassandra, it can only push data to UI, I want to first get data from Cassandra and then push to UI (where I can use Socket.io)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you could set a timer that polls the database every X  milliseconds and send out a update if there is new information. This will not be "real-time" but could be enough for your need. This will also waste som performance because of polling.

What you could do to solve this is to send out updates to the client at the same time you add content to your database. You could use http://socket.io/ to push updates out to the client.

So when you do something like:`db.insert(data)` you also `io.emit(data)` and send it to your clients at "real-time"

Comment: the data into database (my case its cassandra) is coming for other system, spark streaming. if node js had to insert data then I would not have asked this questions. :)

Comment: but yes one solution could be polling database every X milliseconds but you rightly pointed out it will not be a real time.